# Make $routeProvider listen for $rootscope.$broadcast

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've added this module to my app: https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth/blob/gh-pages/lib/http-auth-interceptor.js

It broadcasts a message on 401 responses, very handy!  Just not sure how I can make my $routeProvider listen for the $rootscope.$broadcast.  I'd like to redirect to the sign-in page on 401s.

My $routeProvide looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('demoApp', ['http-auth-interceptor','tastypieModule'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) { $routeProvider.
        when('/', {controller:HomeCrtl, templateUrl:'partials/home.html'}).
        when('/sign-in', {controller:SiginInCtrl, templateUrl:'partials/sign-in.html'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't make your $routeProvider listen for it. You would simply listen for it in your controller, and then use $location to send your application to the appropriate route.

```
app.controller('MainAppCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('event:auth-loginConfirmed', function(){
          $location.path('/');
    });
});
```

EDIT: As you likely have a lot of controllers, you'd want to have a parent controller that wraps your ngView...

```
<div ng-controller="MainAppCtrl">
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above controller will now be present for all views, and is sure to register your listener.

Comment: My $routeProvider will have lots of controllers. I'm looking for a global way of listening for 401s.

Comment: Brill works (makes more sense to have this event though: "event:auth-loginRequired")  Thanks :)